# An equality of sets involving two directions

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

LEt $A,B$ be sets. Prove that $A \subseteq B \iff P(A) \subseteq P(B) $.

Attempt:

First, take any element of $P(A)$, say $Y$, we know by definition that $Y \subseteq A$ and so $Y \subseteq B$ (given). Therefore, by definition $Y \in P(B)$. and we have the result.

Conversely, suppose $x \in A$, then $\{x\} \in P(A)$ and so $\{ x \} \in P(B)$. (Can we conclude that $x \in B$) ?

Comment: That looks good. For the converse you could also say: $A\in\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$ so $A\in\wp(B)$, i.e. $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that looks right.

For the single remaining step, once you know that $\{x\}\in\mathcal P(B)$, this is the same as $\{x\}\subseteq B$, which again means that $x\in B$, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is okay.

Alternative for converse:

$A\in\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)\implies A\in\wp(B)$, i.e. $A\subseteq B$

Answer (score 0):

You have the ($\implies$) direction right. As for the converse, you're almost there:

( $\Longleftarrow$ ) If $x\in A$, then $\{x\} \subseteq A$, so $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$; hence $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. This means the same thing as $\{x\} \subseteq B$; in turn, the last statement is equivalent to $x\in B$.

Just expand the definitions involved in "$\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(B)$" and you'll see that it's equivalent to "$\{x\} \subseteq B$" and ultimately to "$x\in B$".

Comment: Is giving a whole fresh proof write-up really helpful when what the OP was asking must have been whether his existing (almost complete) proof attempt is good?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Better now I hope.

Answer (score -2):

I am afraid you seem to be getting a little confused on notation $\in$ is used to denote an element belonging to a set and $\subset$ is when saying a set is a subset of another set.

Anyway to show the converse assume the right hand side of the implication and let $x\in A$ then $x \in P(A)$ indeed taking the subset with just the element $x$ then $x \in P(B)$ and since $x$ is just a single element if $x \in P(B)$ then it follow $x \in B$ and we have proved the converse.

The first direction is fine one you sort out the notation. I think just need to make sure you are clear on notation.

Comment: I don't see any confusion between $\subseteq$ and $\in$ in the question. Where do you think there's an error?

Comment: On the other hand _you_ seem to be confused between subsets and elements when you propose reasoning from $x\in A$ to $x\in\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: I am afraid you seem to be getting a little confused on it yourself.